# Pentaho CDE Chart component error

Tags: charts, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I have an issue.
Datasource panel i am calling stored procedure.
And based on the parameter which i select my table and chart has to load.
And it is working perfectly fine,

But when i just load the dashboard, i am expecting nothing in place of table as well as chart.
For table part nothing is coming (no data) that is what i wanted but for chart error processing component is coming. So do i have to set any default values or something for chart?

So what should i do for this?

Note: Once i select parameter(value from dropdown) everything is working properly.

Comment: You have to set default value for that parameter. Your problem will solve..

Comment: Yes.
But not finding anything in properties where i have to specify.

Comment: In simple parameter you can do..

Comment: I am using the single parameter for table as well as chart.
Still let me try.

Comment: @VenkateshPanabaka as i am using same parameter at multiple locations this will not work for me. any other solution?

Comment: i have sent you invite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to execute a component as soon as dashboard is loaded, you may try following:

1. Go to components tab.
2. On the right pane click "Advanced properties".
3. Set `Execute at start` to False.

Now your component should be executed only after one one of listened parameters is changed.

Answer (score 0):

In the Simple Parameter - there is a "Property Value". Place your default value there.

Comment: i am using same parameter at multiple places in one dashboard..
so this is not directly suitable for me.
i only want to set default property of charts. because error message is only displaying for charts not for other things.

Comment: Maybe you should de-link the parameters. Use a separate parameter for the chart. That way you can manage each one separately. There is no other way to set the default value within the chart properties itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by playing with the priority property, this is from 1 to 5, and it somehow sets the order of execution, you can give priority 1, to whatever fills the parameter that you will use in the graph, and leave the priority as graph 5 has by default, so when the chart has run the parameter value is alredy defined, I hope to help you, greetings